# Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory - InaccessibleObjectException

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa, entity, persistence

I want to make a Dao unit test to test my class BasicDao.
I try to create an entity Student1 in a memory db.
I make a simple entity with a simple table with one field.
But I have an error message that I don't understand (see stacktrace at the end)

Persitence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="h2-in-memory-pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        
        <!-- Entities -->
        <class>be.etnic.moodlecustom.lib.model.Student1</class>
        
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" 
                value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:/resources/create.sql'\;RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:/resources/data.sql'" />

            <!--Hibernate properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="MOODAGE" />
            <property name="wildfly.jpa.default-unit" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Class Student1

```
@Table(name="STUDENT1")
@Entity
public class Student1 implements Serializable {
@Id
private Integer ID;

public Student1() {}

public Integer getID() {
    return ID;
}
public void setID(Integer iD) {
    ID = iD;
}
```

}

Structure table

```
CREATE SCHEMA MOODAGE;

CREATE TABLE MOODAGE.STUDENT1(
    ID INTEGER
);
```

BasicDaoTest Class

```
class BasicDaoTest {
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private static EntityManager em;
    private BasicDao basicDao = new BasicDao();
    
    
    @BeforeAll
    static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("h2-in-memory-pu");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    //    em.clear();
    //    em.close();
    //    emf.close();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        basicDao.setEm(em);
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    void testSetEm() {
        assertNotNull(em);
    }

    @Test
    void testFindAll() {
        List<Student1> students = basicDao.findAll(em, Student1.class);
        assertNotNull(students);
    }
```

POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>be.etnic.moodlecustom-batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>moodlecustom-batch</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>moodlecustom-batch-lib</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<!-- Describe this module -->
<description>moodle batch lib</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>be.etnic.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-lib</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JPA for Java EE application servers -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope> <!-- provided if youre deploying to jboss as 7.1 -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20201115</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
      <version>6.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pack-sql</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipAssembly>false</skipAssembly>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/wsdl/src/gen/java</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                        </wsdlOptions>

                        <defaultOptions>
                            <autoNameResolution>true</autoNameResolution>
                            <noAddressBinding>true</noAddressBinding>
                        </defaultOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>3.0.0</version> -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-generated-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/openapi/src/gen/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <sourceFileExcludes>
                    <sourceFileExclude>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/**</sourceFileExclude>
                </sourceFileExcludes>
                <excludePackageNames>be.etnic.ddle.*,be.etnic.esb.*,
                    be.etnic.glob.*, be.cfwb.enseignement.*, be.etnic.types.*,
                    be.etnic.services_web.*, be.etnic.transversal.*,
                    org.alfresco.ws.*, be.etnic.alfresco.*
                </excludePackageNames>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Stacktrace
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: h2-in-memory-pu] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:951)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at be.etnic.moodlecustom.lib.dao.BasicDaoTest.setUpBeforeClass(BasicDaoTest.java:27)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:126)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeAllMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:68)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllMethods$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:384)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllMethods(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:196)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:136)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:128)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:297)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:493)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:878)
... 61 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.(EntityMetamodel.java:382)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.(AbstractEntityPersister.java:510)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88)
... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @5c3bd550
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103)
at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass2(FactoryHelper.java:181)
at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:164)
at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:507)
at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:492)
at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:428)
at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:400)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:72)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:158)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:58)
... 82 more

Comment: The solution was to add resources test in Pom.change the path of web-inf in path resources

Comment: could you please elaborate?